# Angular Material click next month or previous month not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

Code snippet:

```
<mat-calendar *ngIf="dataAvailable" #openCalendar [dateClass]="getAttendance()" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)" (monthSelected)="monthSelected($event)"> </mat-calendar>
```

Angular Material does not gives any option to call some event while clicking on next and previous month. Is there work around if we need to use Angular Material calendar?

Comment: '_clicking on next and previous month_', do you mean the arrows from right top corner?

Comment: Do you mean ‘mat-datepicker’? The datepicker offers an (input) and (change) event as well as a (dateInput) and (dateChange) event.

Comment: Possibly have a look at this page. It could help. https://onthecode.co.uk/angular-material-calendar-component/

Comment: Yes i mean clicking on arrows.

Comment: I am using mat-calendar not mat-date picker.  It seems in the library only two output events are there. No event is provided on click of next and previous arrows

Answer (score 1):

For those who still search a solution for this problem, you can access the previous & next arrows with query selectors in ngAfterViewInit, its maybe not the best way but it works for me

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const BACK_BUTTON = document.querySelector('.mat-calendar-previous-button');
  const FORWARD_BUTTON = document.querySelector('.mat-calendar-next-button');
  if (BACK_BUTTON) {
    this.renderer.listen(BACK_BUTTON, 'click', () => {
      console.log(this.dateAdapter.today());
      if (this.calendarDate.getMonth() === 0) {
        this.calendarDate.setFullYear(this.calendarDate.getFullYear() - 1);
        this.calendarDate.setMonth(11);
      } else {
        this.calendarDate.setMonth(this.calendarDate.getMonth() - 1);
      }
    });
  }
  if (FORWARD_BUTTON) {
    this.renderer.listen(FORWARD_BUTTON, 'click', () => {
      if (this.calendarDate.getMonth() === 11) {
        this.calendarDate.setFullYear(this.calendarDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        this.calendarDate.setMonth(0);
      } else {
        this.calendarDate.setMonth(this.calendarDate.getMonth() + 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
```